# Haskell: f :: hex String -> Integer using tail recursion

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a way to change hex to an integer using tail recursion.  So far I've only tried terrible implementations of regular primitive recursion and I haven't even gotten close. Very frustrated.  Even examples of tail recursion will help and be greatly appreciated. I don't quite understand it well enough for this implementation.

Example:

- `"005" -> 5`
- `"1E" -> 30`

Restrictions: Cannot use imports or if, then, else etc, must be done with recursion if possible or tail recursion.

My attempt at recursion.

```
    hexToInteger :: String -> Integer
        |(x:xs) = []        = []
        |x == 0             = hexToInteger xs
        |otherwise          = addition x + hexToInteger xs

    addition :: String -> Integer
    addition x 
        |--something to check what position we're dealing with and what hex value.
        |--Return the Integer value
```

Comment: What did you try? Is it a homework?

Comment: So far I've only tried terrible implementations of regular primitive recursion and I haven't even gotten close.  Very frustrated.Even examples of tail recursion will help.  I don't quite understand it well enough for this implementation.

Edit: I'll put this in the description.

Comment: Can you implement non-tail recursive solution? It could be good starting point.

Comment: Please post you implementation, even if it is "terrible".

Comment: Nope, I've only tried terrible implementations of regular primitive recursion and haven't even gotten close.  I thought it may have been way to hard to do it this way as I've been failing miserably,  which is why I'm now trying my hand at tail recursion.  If it's possible for primitive recursion any points in the right direction would be huge for me.  Thanks for reading btw!

Comment: So, you just need to understand recursion. And then you'll be able to solve our task :)
Check out that: http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion

Comment: Well I would check if the string was empty if so return empty, then if the front of the string was a 0, if so just recurse on hexToInteger, otherwise use a helperfunction to add the hex values, which is kind of where i'm stuck on the recursion part.  I'm not sure how to use recursion taking different values of hex to add them together without using a huge charmap which is also not allowed.

Comment: You can use `Enum` instance of 'Char' instead of charmap. `fromEnum 'E' -> 69`

Comment: hexadecimal won't always start with a '0' then you will have more than one case to manage, and i guess the recursion part is not the harden one. Please post your code. You can't say "this is what I want and how I require to be done (restriction)". But You said "I'm not sure how to use recursion taking different values of hex to add them together without using a huge charmap which is also not allowed" Its a good start, may be its the question you have to ask about and provide a little example and I'm sure you'll be helped a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Generally, for tail-recursive functions, you need an accumulator argument -- with purity, the result could otherwise only depend on the base case reached. So you would need a helper function taking also an accumulator argument, and call that with an initial value for the accumulator,

```
hexToInteger :: String -> Integer
hexToInteger string = hexToIntegerHelper initialAccumulator string
```

and you must find out

- what initial value you should pass for the accumulator
- how the accumulator has to be updated in each step.

For example, a tail-recursive implementation of `reverse` is

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse xs = reverseHelper [] xs

reverseHelper :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
reverseHelper accumulator [] = accumulator
reverseHelper accumulator (x:xs) = reverseHelper (x:accumulator) xs
```

and a tail-recursive factorial (fudging the case of a negative argument)

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n = factorialHelper 1 n

factorialHelper :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
factorialHelper accumulator n
    | n < 2     = accumulator
    | otherwise = factorialHelper (n*accumulator) (n-1)
```

So you can see the general structure of `hexToIntegerHelper`,

```
hexToIntegerHelper :: Integer -> String -> Integer
hexToIntegerHelper accumulator "" = accumulator
hexToIntegerHelper accumulator (d:ds) = hexToIntegerHelper (newAccumulatorFrom accumulator d) ds
```

and the question is how the new accumulator is to be computed from the old one and the hexadecimal digit (and what the initial accumulator should be).

For the updating of the accumulator,

```
digitToInt :: Char -> Int
```

from `Data.Char` could be useful, that handles all hexadecimal digits. But, it doesn't return the desired type, so you'd need to use a `fromIntegral` or a `toInteger` to convert the `Int` to `Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two recursive functions, although it has been pointed out to me that they are not tail recursive. Maybe they can help you get there, though.

```
hexToInteger :: String -> Integer
hexToInteger [] = 0
hexToInteger str = 
  fromIntegral z + 16 * hexToInteger (init str)
    where z = let y = last str 
              in if y >= 'A' && y <= 'Z' 
                    then fromEnum y - 55 
                    else if y >= 'a' && y <= 'z'
                            then fromEnum y - 87
                            else fromEnum y - 48



hexToInteger :: String -> Integer
hexToInteger [] = 0
hexToInteger str = 
  z + 16 * hexToInteger (init str)
    where z = case last str of 
                '0' -> 0 
                '1' -> 1 
                '2' -> 2 
                '3' -> 3 
                '4' -> 4 
                '5' -> 5 
                '6' -> 6 
                '7' -> 7 
                '8' -> 8 
                '9' -> 9 
                'A' -> 10 
                'B' -> 11 
                'C' -> 12 
                'D' -> 13 
                'E' -> 14 
                'F' -> 15
                'a' -> 10 
                'b' -> 11 
                'c' -> 12 
                'd' -> 13 
                'e' -> 14 
                'f' -> 15
                otherwise -> 0
```

Comment: Neither of these functions is tail recursive - try writing them in prefix form and it will be obvious that they aren't.

Comment: @stephen ...thank you for pointing that out, I did not know the difference between tail and other recursion.

Answer (score 0):

We can implement this the same way you would convert a hexadecimal string on paper: Initialize your output to 0, then read the string from left to right, each time multiplying your result by 16 and adding the new digit.

Create and call a private function with an accumulator argument initialized to 0:

```
hex2int s = hex2int' s 0
    where
```

The base case of the recursion takes an empty string and returns the accumulator:

```
        hex2int' "" n = n
```

The recursive case takes the first character of the string and increases the accumulator accordingly.

```
        hex2int' (c:s) n = hex2int' s ((n * 16) + (hexDigit2int c))
```

`hexDigit2int` is a simple lookup.

```
        hexDigit2int c
          | c == "0" = 0

         ...

          | c == "f" = 15
```